# Drawing spherical harmonics with pst-3dplot

Tags: pstricks, plot, wolfram-mathematica, pst-solides3d, pst-3dplot

For my lecture notes in theoretical physics (namely quantum mechanics) I'm trying to visualize the spherical harmonics. I got Mathematica to plot them an this is what I did:

```
SphericalPlot3D[(Sqrt[3/(4*Pi)]*Sin[theta]*Cos[phi])^2,
  {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

That gives me this picture:

[image: Spherical Harmonic]

Now I want to plot it using `pst-3dplot` (or `pst-solides3d`) but I don't know how since there is no option like `SphericalPlot3D`. I tried using `\parametricplotThreeD` but this doesn't output anything useful. Here is my MWE for this

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\begin{document}

\centering
\psset{algebraic=true}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-3.5)(4,0)
  \parametricplotThreeD[SphericalCoor=true](0,\psPi)(0,\psPiTwo)%
    {t | u | (sqrt(3/(4*\psPi))*sin(t)*cos(u))^2}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

This is the output

[image: Useless image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function `\parametricplotThreeD` takes the x,y,z-coordinates of the surface as arguments, whereas t and u are polar and azimuthal angles. The following code gives what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\begin{document}

\centering
\psset{algebraic=true}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-3.5)(4,0)
  \parametricplotThreeD[SphericalCoor=true](0,\psPi)(0,\psPiTwo)%
    { cos(u)^3*sin(t)^3 | sin(u)*sin(t)^3*cos(u)^2 | cos(t)*sin(t)^2*cos(u)^2 }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Another option for nice 3D plots is Asymptote, see the [gallery](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/index.html) which also has a plot of a spherical harmonic.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to Alex' answer I was able to redo the plot using `pst-solides3d`

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(1,1)
  \defFunction[algebraic]{harmonic}(u,v)
  {sin(u)*cos(v)*(sqrt(3/(4*\psPi))*sin(u)*cos(v))^2}
  {sin(u)*sin(v)*(sqrt(3/(4*\psPi))*sin(u)*cos(v))^2}
  {cos(u)*(sqrt(3/(4*\psPi))*sin(u)*cos(v))^2}
  \psSolid[object=surfaceparametree,
    base=0 pi 0 pi 2 mul,
    function=harmonic,
    linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,
    ngrid=25 40
  ]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Spherical harmonic]

Answer (score 4):

The required plot of this function can also be done with pgfplots in a short way with nice output.

I previously posted it on [TikZ.de](http://tikz.de/pgfplots-1-11/). It requires the [recently released pgfplots 1.11](http://latex-community.org/home/news/84-news-latex-graphics-figures-tables/502-pgfplots-1-11), because I used a new feature to globally switch from degree to radian, because here radian is used.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{trig format plots=rad, compat=1.11}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[colormap/violet, hide axis]
    \addplot3[
      surf,
      domain     = 0:pi,
      domain y   = 0:2*pi,
      samples    = 50,
      samples y  = 70,
      z buffer   = sort
    ] 
    ( {sin(x)*cos(y)*(sqrt(3/(4*pi))*sin(x)*cos(y))^2},
      {sin(x)*sin(y)*(sqrt(3/(4*pi))*sin(x)*cos(y))^2},
      {cos(x)*(sqrt(3/(4*pi))*sin(x)*cos(y))^2} );
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Spherical harmonics]